# If I allocate some memory with AllocHGlobal, do I have to free it with FreeHGlobal?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, interop

I wrote a helper method,

```
internal static IntPtr StructToPtr(object obj)
{
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
    return ptr;
}
```

Which takes a `struct` and gives me back an `IntPtr` to it. I use it as such:

```
public int Copy(Texture texture, Rect srcrect, Rect dstrect)
{
    return SDL.RenderCopy(_ptr, texture._ptr, Util.StructToPtr(srcrect), Util.StructToPtr(dstrect));
}
```

The problem is that I only need that `IntPtr` for a split second so that I can pass it off to the C DLL,

```
[DllImport("SDL2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SDL_RenderCopy")]
internal static extern int RenderCopy(IntPtr renderer, IntPtr texture, IntPtr srcrect, IntPtr dstrect);
```

I don't really want to have to worry about freeing it; otherwise my 1-line function grows to 6:

```
public int Copy(Texture texture, Rect? srcrect=null, Rect? dstrect=null)
{
    var srcptr = Util.StructToPtr(srcrect);
    var dstptr = Util.StructToPtr(dstrect);
    var result = SDL.RenderCopy(_ptr, texture._ptr, srcptr, dstptr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(srcptr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dstptr);
    return result;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Will C# eventually clean up any memory it has allocated?

If not, is there a way I can wrap the call to `SDL.RenderCopy` in some `using` statements instead so that I don't have to do all this temporary variable + explicit freeing non-sense?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, C# will not automatically free memory allocated by `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.  That memory must be freed with a call to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` or else it will be leaked.

You could create something a smart pointer to wrap the `IntPtr`

```
class StructWrapper : IDisposable {
    public IntPtr Ptr { get; private set; }

    public StructWrapper(object obj) {
         if (Ptr != null) {
             Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj));
             Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, Ptr, false);
         }
         else {
             Ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
         }
    }

    ~StructWrapper() {
        if (Ptr != IntPtr.Zero) {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr);
            Ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
       Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr);
       Ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public static implicit operator IntPtr(StructWrapper w) {
        return w.Ptr;
    }
}
```

Using this wrapper you can either manually free the memory by wrapping the object in a `using` statement or by allowing it to be freed when the finalizer runs.

Comment: +1 The only thing that would make this better is an `implicit` conversion to `IntPtr` so it could be passed to his API call without the need for `.Ptr`.

Comment: though, if you only have to do it in this one function, I wouldn't introduce this. Because if I follow what you are doing, you want it as snappy as possible

Comment: Just one more change I would make is to allow the constructor to take `null` and initialize `Ptr` to `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: I'm assuming this struct we've just developed is CC licensed? :-)

Comment: This answer really is just re-inventing [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx), however SafeHandle has the benefit of having the deallocation be a Constrained Execution Region so it can not be interrupted by something like a `Thread.Abort()`, it also can be directly returned from P/Invoke calls.

Comment: As the ctor is currently (2015/05/09) written (`if (Ptr != null)`) I think it is wrong.  Shouldn't the ctor be checking `obj` to see if it is null and setting `Ptr` accordingly?  Reading Mark's suggestion from Jul 10 '13 at 4:40.

Answer (score 24):

A lot of people don't know this (and that's why you got so many answers saying you can't), but there is something built in to .NET just for things like that: [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx).

In fact, the .NET 2.0 page for [one of its derived classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#code-snippet-4) has a example using `AllocHGlobal`. When the finalizer of the `SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle` is called it will automatically call `FreeHGlobal` for you. (If you want deterministic cleanup instead of just waiting for the finalizer to get around to it you will need to either call `Close()` or `Dispose()` explicitly).

It just takes a few code changes on your part:

```
internal static SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle StructToPtr(object obj)
{
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
    return new SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle(ptr, true);
}

[DllImport("SDL2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SDL_RenderCopy")]
internal static extern int RenderCopy(IntPtr renderer, IntPtr texture, SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle srcrect, SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle dstrect);
```

Once you do that your original `Copy` example will work exactly like you expected it to.

```
public int Copy(Texture texture, Rect srcrect, Rect dstrect)
{
    return SDL.RenderCopy(_ptr, texture._ptr, Util.StructToPtr(srcrect), Util.StructToPtr(dstrect));
}
```

When the two pointers go out of scope and are finalized they will be cleaned up afterwards. I don't know how `_ptr` is used or if `Texture` is a class you control but those could potentially be switched to `SafeHandle`s too.

---

**UPDATE:** If you want to learn more about how to properly deal with unmanaged resources (and get a example of a better pattern of how to implement `IDisposable` better than the example the MSDN gives) I highly recommend the article "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)" by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary). He goes into depth on how to properly write your own SafeHandles in the article.

---

**APPENDIX**

Here is a copy of the example in case the link ever goes dead:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace SafeHandleExamples
{
    class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10);

            Console.WriteLine("Ten bytes of unmanaged memory allocated.");

            SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle memHandle = new SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle(ptr, true);

            if (memHandle.IsInvalid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle is invalid!.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle class initialized to unmanaged memory.");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    // Demand unmanaged code permission to use this class.
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
    sealed class SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        // Set ownsHandle to true for the default constructor.
        internal SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle() : base(true) { }

        // Set the handle and set ownsHandle to true.
        internal SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle(IntPtr preexistingHandle, bool ownsHandle)
            : base(ownsHandle)
        {
            SetHandle(preexistingHandle);
        }

        // Perform any specific actions to release the 
        // handle in the ReleaseHandle method.
        // Often, you need to use Pinvoke to make
        // a call into the Win32 API to release the 
        // handle. In this case, however, we can use
        // the Marshal class to release the unmanaged
        // memory.
        override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            // "handle" is the internal
            // value for the IntPtr handle.

            // If the handle was set,
            // free it. Return success.
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                // Free the handle.
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);

                // Set the handle to zero.
                handle = IntPtr.Zero;

                // Return success.
                return true;
            }

            // Return false. 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Fantastic. Why wouldn't `SafeUnmanagedMemoryHandle` be part of the BCL, considering the common use of `AllocHGlobal`?

Comment: Don't know, they also removed the examples from the MSDN for versions after 2.0

Comment: Interesting. I see `SafeHandle` used for things like PInvoked calls to `CreateFile`, but I wonder why they'd get rid of something like this. I'm not even sure who here would know.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. I'll tweak shf301's class to use SafeHandle instead. The example on MSDN is a little weird though; why the explicit check for `if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)` if `ReleaseHandle` is only called "if the handle is valid as defined by the IsInvalid property" ([src](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.releasehandle.aspx))?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to Free it,  and the way you have got it as your 6 line program is pretty efficient.  Its the tradeoff you make when stepping outside the garbage collector.

Comment: Only problem with his current code is that `SDL.RenderCopy` might throw an exception (don't know for sure, haven't checked the documentation), in which case he would leak memory because the free methods never get executed.

Comment: don't think it does, but if it did, it would be a problem.

Comment: All the SDL methods return 0 on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no built-in automatic way to do this. If you call [`AllocHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx), you *must* explicitly free it with [`FreeHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx) (unless you are okay with potentially massive memory leaks).

> This memory must be released using the [`Marshal.FreeHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx) method.

What I've done in the past, is wrap up my `AllocHGlobal` allocations in an `IDisposable` wrapper class, where `Dispose()` calls `FreeHGlobal` on the pointer. This way, I *could* put them in a `using` statement.

Comment: \**cough*\* [yes there is a automatic way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17563315/80274) \**cough*\*